# How to return empty array or resultset from a query with mysqli_fetch_all()?

Tags: php, mysqli, resultset

My PHP code:

```
function get_something() {

  global $link;

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM new";

  $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

  $names = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  return $names;

}
```

What is my problem:

When my table `new` is empty, I get the following error:

> mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result`

If it isn't empty everything is working fine.

I need to check if my database is empty and if it's not, I will call `mysqli_fetch_all`.  Otherwise, my function should return an empty array.

How is this possible to do?

Comment: You can always call `mysqli_fetch_all()`. But when `mysqli_query()` is returning `false` you have an error in the execution of your SQL query. Check with `mysqli_error()` what the error is.

Comment: @Progman you raise a valid point. For OPs query however the only likelihood for `mysqli_query` to return false (assuming a valid connection has been made) is if the table doesn't exist. I've incorporated that scenario into my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mysqli_num_rows($result)` to check how many rows were returned from the query. But if table `new` doesn't exist, `$result` will be `false` so we have to check that `$result` is valid as well:

```
if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    $names = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
else
    $names = array();
return $names;
```

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) generates an indexed array of associative arrays.  When there are no rows found, it will deliver an empty array (which is what you want).  It is absolutely pointless to call `mysqli_num_rows()`, **so don't make your script do any unnecessary work**.

Furthermore:

- many developers will advise you not to make `global` declarations to pass variables in your custom function scope.  Instead, pass the connection variable into your function as a parameter.
- I always try to avoid declaring single use variables.  For your case, `$sql` and `$names` will only be used/referenced once after being declared, so just don't declare them.
- As a matter of personal preference, I recommend using OO syntax with `mysqli` functions because it is less verbose, but in my following snippet I'll leave it like your original post.

Suggested Code:

```
function get_something($link) {
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM new")) {
        return [];  // check mysqli_error($link) because your query failed
    }
    return mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```